# No subscription with SqlDependency

Tags: c#, mono, sqldependency

I am trying to write a code using SqlDependency to register for notifications, but I can't make it work. I first tried in .Net with Visual studio and then compiled it to Mono. Here is my code : http://pastebin.com/c6kZBwwU

In the .Net Platform, it works perfectly fine. However in Mono, I don't get notifications.

I did a little research and looked at what Sql Server receives for both applications:

Mono trace :
[image: Trace for the Mono version]

.Net trace :
[image: Trace for the .Net version]

As you can see, it seems that Mono doesn't send the necessary requests to Sql Server… Is the implementation broken, or did I miss something ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this in the end because I am running in to the same problem now

Comment: @knocte was right, it was not implemented at this time. I will check again when I have some time and I'll let you now by adding an answer

Comment: I tried to use it but it wasn't firing the event

Answer (score -3):

> Is the implementation broken, or did I miss something ?

*Broken* is not the word. It may be **incomplete**. And as Mono is an opensource project, it is waiting for your pull requests to improve it.

Comment: Before I tried this in Mono, I checked this page : http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility which states that .Net 2.0 is fully implemented, and SqlDependency is a .Net 2.0 class.

Comment: that is just a guideline, you found an element where that guideline is not entirely accurate